# ROR + Replace the last character by detecting it using ruby code by another character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to detect the last character of string in ruby on rails and replace it by "".
Explanation :: Suppose I have string as "demo-" then i have to check its last character, If it is "-" then replace it by "", otherwise no action should be taken.

Example - Code ::

```
search_text.downcase! if !search_text.nil?
```

now if seach_text have value as "demo-" then change it to "demo" by replacing "-".

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much simpler:

```
text.chomp!('-')
```

chomp already includes the if condition: if the character exists at the end of the string, it is removed.

Comment: Thanx buddy, really this method is quite very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
> a = "abc-"
=> "abc-"
>> a.chop! if a[-1] == 45 # if last character is a minus sign chop it off
=> 45
>> a
=> "abc"
```

Comment: is not it better to use `a[-1, 1] == '-'`?

Comment: @tig, could you explain why? is it clearer?  i was going for brevity as long as the operation is pretty simple

Comment: I guess it is because of converting character to char code. "-" is better for eyes than a 45

Answer (score -1):

try the following

```
text.chop! if text[text.length-1,1] == "-"
```

text.chop! removes the last character and saves it to the same object

Comment: should be `text[text.length - 1, 1]` or `text[-1, 1]`

Comment: Thanx buddy, It works... I found alternate option to solve my problem rather than this one. but this is fine one...

Comment: You could share the alternate option here if you can :)

Comment: Friend actually In first step, I am accessing value from string, but now I am using array for this. so my problem was solve by using zeroth value of array.

Comment: Dude, Your method is quite lengthy in code and complicated. Please see the below code of Mark. Really very much helpful.